# Assembly ARM Instruction Explanation

Tags: assembly, arm

I need someone to explain in detail the following instruction:

```
.text:000084AC                 PUSH    {R3,LR}
.text:000084AE                 LDR     R0, =0x111C
.text:000084B0                 ADD     R0, PC
.text:000084B2                 BL      sub_9354
.text:000084B6                 MOVS    R0, #1
.text:000084B8                 POP     {R3,PC}
```

Comment: It's a function that calls another function with the first argument being the address of something and then returns 1.

Comment: Smells like homework. General expectation is OP should  show some effort first. Problem is you can have hundreds of this type of questions without them giving anything back to other developers.

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."- Help center

Comment: not homework at all, im learning assembly to decompile a game library file, thats where this code comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular set of instruction represent subroutine inside main assembly program. Lets understand each instruction one by one :

> .text:000084AC                 PUSH    {R3,LR}

```
PUSH <register_list>
```

Register_list can be from r0-r7 and LR. `PUSH` Pushes multiple registers to the stack in Thumb state.

`PUSH`- push register on to the stack

In layman term you can say "Enter in subroutine"

> .text:000084AE                 LDR     R0, =0x111C

`LDR` -  Load register from memory

```
LDR rd, =numeric constant
LDR     R0, =0x111C => generate LDR R0, #0x111c
```

> ADD     R0, PC

```
ADD op{S}{cond} {Rd,} Rn, Operand2
```

Here in your case Rd is omitted so Rd=Rn here. So

```
R0=Program counter + R0
```

> .text:000084B2                 BL      sub_9354

Branch with Link (BL) writes the old PC into the link register (R14) of the current bank.

```
B{L}{cond} <expression>
```

is the destination. The assembler calculates the offset.
BL - Branch with link 
This instruction forces program counter `pc` to point to  a new address

> MOVS    R0, #1

```
MOV<opcode>{cond}{S} Rd,<Op2>
```

`MOV` Move register or constant

If S is present (implied for CMP, CMN, TEQ,
TST) then move constant 1 to R0

> POP     {R3,PC}

`POP` - pop registers from stack

In layman term you can say "return from subroutine".

Upon return R3 is popped off the stack as well as the return address being loaded into the pc. This returns from the subroutine. 
Reference taken from

http://infocenter.arm.com/

http://bear.ces.cwru.edu/eecs_382/ARM7-TDMI-manual-pt2.pdf

[ARM system Developer's Guide](http://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/17030-102-1-52869/ARM%20System%20Developers%20Guide-Designing%20and%20Optimizing%20System%20Software.pdf)

Comment: I think you missed one of the most important points, the `add r0,pc` puts where ever the code is running *+0x111c* in r0 and then uses `bl` (also PC relative) to call a routine where the `r0` is a parameter.  So the assembly can run from anywhere as long as the binary blob is relocated together/in-tact.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out @artlessnoise I would be thankful to you if you could modify my answer and add information . Because you can correctly add it otherwise just let me know I will  add as I know